# How to dispose a crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal report. I have to generate reports with multiple pages. How to dispose reports after use. i tried the following code.

```
protected void CrystalReportViewer1_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  report.Close();
  report.Dispose();
}
```

But it gives error when i am trying to navigate to other pages.
Can anyone suggest a way to dispose report? In which event we suppose to close the report?

Comment: what the error says?

Comment: Show the ERROR here..!!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure and call garbage collection manually after disposing a report or form with viewer on it. Crytal/.Net does not clean up properly (or fast enough) if you don't.